# Display SP value as percentage in Powerapp form

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have a SharePoint list with a column that is displayed as a percentage: the minimum value is 0, the maximum is 100:

[image]

This is displayed nicely as percentage value, i.e. 11%

[image]

However, when I am trying to use PowerApps as an input form, it allows only values between 0 and 1

[image]

How to allow users to enter the percentage value instead of a fraction (so 11% instead of 0.11)?

Comment: Is there existing real time data in your list (or you are just trying this in development environment)? If No, I can suggest you a workaround.

Comment: @GaneshSanap It is still in development, I've been thinking about changing the list settings to a regular number and informing users that this is in fact a percentage

Comment: Yes. I will suggest you to change it to regular number field (remove show as percentage). Then apply JSON/column formatting in list view to show that number as percentile by appending `%` (If you want to use this approach I can give you the JSON code to append `%` in list view). Also, in powerapps you can concatenate `%` on display form using formulas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

[image]

Here "Numbers" is the name of my column.

This makes both the display of the value (The **Default** property) and the function that updates it (**Update**) stores the value correctly.

Comment: Could not find `Update` property on the DataCardValue field. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It is under the Advanced tab - you might have to press "Unlock to change properties" and then "More options" for them to be visible.

Comment: Got it.. I was searching for `Update` on the "DataCardValue" (text input field), while it is present on the "DataCard".

Comment: Thank you so much @Rune

Answer (score 2):

Per my test, percentage is acceptable in PowerApps form. Symbol `%` needs to be typed in manually as well.

Please point it out if I have misunderstood your situation.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is default behavior in PowerApps for number fields which are being shown as percentage in SharePoint because it stores values from 0 to 1 in back-end.

**Workaround**:

1. Change your number field to regular number field (by removing show as percentage in column settings).
2. Use JSON/Column formatting to show this field as percentage in list view.

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "= @currentField + '%'"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**References**:

1. [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting).

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint answer is simple - no JSON code is required. A percentage is a decimal value less than 1. If you want your column to read 44%, then you have to enter it at .44. SharePoint will convert it to a % in the column. This will work regardless of how people enter data in your list - default form, quick edit, details pane, etc.

As for getting it to display in Power Apps, I'm working on that myself. I assume it has to do with Format.

Comment: Hi - the question was about how to make it user friendly: if you know that you are entering percentage value, it is better to enter 55 instead 0.55. You would be surprised how many people don't realize that percentage is indeed a fraction.